# Insert Charc into String in a Range where character X exist at Index - swift 2.0

Tags: string, swift, swift2

Please could somebody help me.

I am trying to add a new line (\n) into an existing string.

Lets say the string is 20+ Characters long, I want to find a space " " between the range of 15 and 20 then inset a new line (\n) just after the index to where the char " " (space) is

I hope that makes sense :F

Code i have for this so far is as follows

```
       var newString = string
        newString[newString.startIndex..< newString.startIndex.advancedBy(16)]

       /* let startIndex = newString.startIndex.advancedBy(16)
        let endIndex = newString.endIndex

        let newRange = startIndex ..< endIndex

        print("start index = \(newRange)")*/

        let range: Range<String.Index> = newString.rangeOfString(" ")!
        let index: Int = newString.startIndex.distanceTo(range.startIndex) 


        newString.insert("\n", atIndex: newString.startIndex.advancedBy(index))
        label.text = newString
```

if I try the following

```
let newIndex = name.startIndex.advancedBy(19).distanceTo(range.endIndex)
```

I get the error message

> fatal error: can not increment endIndex

Ive got a feeling I'm on the right tracks but the above will inset a new line at the index where space first appears in the string and not between the index of e.g. 15 and 20

Thanks for your help in advance

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following finds the first space in the range `15..<END_OF_YOUR_STRING`, and replaces it with a new line (`\n`). In your question you stated you explicitly wanted to look for a space in range `15...20`, and also *insert* a new line after the space. Below I have assumed that you actually want:

1. To *replace* the space by a new line, since you'll otherwise have a trailing space on the line following the line break.
2. To search for the first space starting at index `15`, but continuing until you find one (otherwise: if you find no space within range `15...20`, no line break should be inserted?).

Both of these deviations from your question can be quite easily reverted, so tell me if you'd prefer me to follow your instructions to specifically to the point (rather than including my own reason), and I'll update this answer.

Solution as follows:

```
var foo = "This is my somewhat long test string"
let bar = 15 /* find first space " " starting from index 'bar' */
if let replaceAtIndex = foo[foo.startIndex.advancedBy(bar)..<foo.endIndex]
    .rangeOfString(" ")?.startIndex.advancedBy(bar) {

    foo = foo.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(
        replaceAtIndex...replaceAtIndex, withString: "\n")
}

print(foo)
/* This is my somewhat
   long test string    */
```

Note that there is a off-by-one difference between finding a space in the *range of 15 to 20* and the *15:th to 20:th character* (the latter is in the range `14...19`). Above, we search for the first space starting at the 16th character (index `15`).

Comment: Thanks dfri I'll give that a go later and mark the answer as correct all being well. It to me makes perfect sense

Comment: @Tom Happy to help! Take your time.

Comment: Im still getting the fatal error: can not increment endIndex.. i assume its because its not finding a space thus i need to add a catch somewhere

Comment: @Tom To my simple example above or to an implementation beyond this example?

Comment: How would you adapt this catch error if space is not found after given bar number

Comment: @Tom In my example above, if a space is not found after a given `bar` (start)index (to the endindex), the string will simply not be split (as we wont enter the conditional binding clause; `if let`...). So this is not really an _error_ in this context (just a "cannot find"). In this case, you'll have to decide how your program should handle this: is it ok _not to split_ a string with no spaces after given start index? (If so: just as above, don't enter `if let`). If not, throw some error (`enum MyErrors : ErrorType { ... some cases }`, but this is really not in the scope of this question.

Comment: By using your direction i was able to resolve this particular issue and added an answer . Thanks Again

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to dfri for pointing me in the right direction. Although his answer was correct for my problem specifically I've provided the following code to help

```
if string.characters.count >= 20
    {

        let bar = 15 // where to split the code to begin looking for the character
        let beginString = string.substringWithRange(name.startIndex..<name.startIndex.advancedBy(bar))
        var endString = string[string.startIndex.advancedBy(bar)..<name.endIndex]

      if endString.containsString(" ")
      {
        let range = endString.rangeOfString(" ")

        if let i = range
        {
            endString.insert("\n", atIndex:i.startIndex.advancedBy(1) )
            let newString = "\(beginString)\(endString)"
            label.text = newString
        }

        }

    }
```